# Galois group of $(X^2+3)(X^5-1)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

**Problem**: Compute the Galois group of $f(X)=(X^2+3)(X^5-1)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Attempt**: The roots of $f$ are $i\sqrt{3},-i\sqrt{3}, \omega^j$, for $j\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $5$th-root of unity. Hence, the splitting field of $f$ is $E_f:=\mathbb{Q}(\omega,i\sqrt{3})$.

Let $g(X)=X^2+3$ and $h(X)=(X^5-1)/(X-1)$. Both $g,h$  are irreducible (why is that true for $h$?), and $g(i\sqrt{3})=h(\omega)=0$. Thus
$$2=[\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3}:\mathbb{Q})]\mid[E_f:\mathbb{Q}],\quad 4=[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]\mid[E_f:\mathbb{Q}],\quad [E_f:\mathbb{Q}]\leq 8.$$
Suppose $[E_f:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, then $[E_f:\mathbb{Q}(\omega)]=1$, that is, $E_f=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$. But $i\sqrt{3}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$. Thus $[E_f:\mathbb{Q}]=8$.

Set $G:=\text{Gal}(E_f/\mathbb{Q})$, $H_1:=\text{Gal}(E_f/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))<G$ and $H_2:=\text{Gal}(E_f/\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3}))<G$. Then, by Galois theorem, $[G:H_1]=[E_f:\mathbb{Q}(\omega)]=4$ and $[G:H_2]=[E_f:\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})]=2$.

My **question** is: where do I go from here? I don't quite understand how to find the Galois group. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Why is that true for $h$?" Apply Eisenstein on $h(x + 1)$ with $p = 5$. In general, this works with any prime instead of $5$.

Comment: There are two simple field isomorphisms, $s,t$ below (instead of $\sigma,\tau$, hard to type), determined on the field generators by:$$\begin{aligned}s(\sqrt{-3})&=-\sqrt{-3}\ ,\\s(\omega)&=\omega\ ,\\[3mm]t(\sqrt{-3})&=\sqrt{-3}\ ,\\t(\omega)&=\omega^2\ .\end{aligned}$$Here $2$ is a generator of $\Bbb F_5^\times$, so that applying repeatedly $t$ on $\omega$ gives a cycle of maximal length: $\omega\to \omega^2\to \omega^4\to\omega^8\to \omega^{16}$ and after start only the last element is $\omega$ again... Now $s$ generates a group $\cong\Bbb Z/2$, $t$ one $\cong\Bbb Z/4$, and $s,t$ commute...

Comment: @dan_fulea But why do those two ismorphisms exist? Why are they determined in that way?

Comment: Can you figure out what $H_1$ and $H_2$ are? Since $H_1,H_2$ are normal in $G$ (why?) we can write $G$ as a product of $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Comment: It is hard to type it here as a comment, but i will try. Why are $s,t$ determined by the above Ansatz? Because $\sqrt{-3}$ and $\omega$ are field generators. Why they exist, i.e. are well defined? Because we map these field generators to "conjugated roots". Well, this last claim depends on the point in the Galois theory where you stay. Some courses or books have one path, some an other path. To have an answer which does not depend on field theory, we use algebra, ring theory....

Comment: We have$$E_f=\frac {\Bbb Q[Y,Z]}{J=\langle(Y^2+3)\ , \ (Z^4+Z^3+Z^2+Z+1)\rangle}\ .$$Here $J$ is the ideal generated by the two polynomials. Consider $S:\Bbb Q[Y,Z]\to\Bbb Q[Y,Z]$ given by $Y\to-Y$, $Z\to Z$. We have $S(J)\subseteq J$, because the $J$-generators are mapped to elements of $J$. So $S$ induces a ring morphism $s$ on the quotient $E_f$. Same for the ring morphism $T$ of $\Bbb Q[Y,Z]$ given by $Y\to Y$ and $Z\to Z^2$. Then $T$ is on $J$-generators $T(Y^2+3)=Y^2+3\in J$, and $T(Z^4+\dots)=T( (Z^5-1)/(Z-1))=(Z^{10}-1)/(Z^2-1)=(Z^5-1)/(Z-1)\cdot(Z^5+1)/(Z+1)\in J$.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This answer supposes knowledge about cyclotomic fields.

First consider the splitting field $K_5$ of $X^5-1$. We know that $\operatorname{Gal}(K_5/\Bbb Q) \cong (\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)^\times$ and its unique quadratic subfield is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$.

Therefore, $X^2+3$ is irreducible over $K_5$ (otherwise we would have another quadratic subfield, namely $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$).

Therefore, $[E_f:\Bbb Q]=8$ and $E_f = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3}) K_5$ (compositum), so $\operatorname{Gal}(E_f/\Bbb Q) \cong \operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})/\Bbb Q) \times \operatorname{Gal}(K_5/\Bbb Q) \cong C_2 \times C_4$.